# Find the smallest multiplicity of k greater or equal than n

Tags: python-2.7

Is it possible to find the smallest multiplicity of k greater or equal than n without if statement?,
in other words smallest number divisible by k greater or equal than n.

I am looking for expression without condition (also without triple operator and so on).

For example,

```
n = 78, k = 10 -----> 80
n = 80, k =10 -------> 80
n = 13, k = 3 -------> 15
n = 14, k =2 ----> 14
n=13, k = 11 ----> 22
```

Comment: *Why*? is this homework?

Answer (score 0):

Abusing the fact that `bool` can be converted to `int`:

```
tests = [(78, 10), (80, 10), (13, 3), (14, 2), (13, 11)]

for n, k in tests:
    print([n, n - n % k + k][int(bool(n % k))])
```

outputs

```
80
80
15
14
22
```

**Explanation**

`[n, n - n % k + k]` just creates a list. The "trick" is the indexing we use: if `n % k` is `0` it means that we want to choose `n`. Otherwise, `int(bool(n % k))` will become `1` which means `n - n % k + k` will be chosen.

Answer (score 0):

This can do the trick

```
x = ((n // k) + (n % k != 0)) * k
```